# How to change sync workers quantity in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to change the value on sync workers, I changed the property

```
catalog.sync.workers
```

By /hac, but my sync cronjob is not repecting the new value. Do I have to restart the server with the new value on the local.properties value or should I change some other property?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `hsqldb` (database) you should update `catalog.sync.workers.hsqldb` instead.

There's no need to restart the server, you can check the method: `CatalogVersionSyncJob#getDefaultMaxThreads`